# How to automate/simulate user navigation of a Java Applet through code?

Tags: c#, java, applet, screen-scraping

I have a legacy external Java Applet application. When I say external, I mean that I do not have access to the source. I am looking for suggestion on how I can, do the following through code:

1. Open the applet in the background.
2. Navigate through the applet selecting a few options
3. Grabbing the output from a TextBox and putting the output in memory so that I can do some processing
4. Close applet.

Comment: Do you have access to the classes of the applet? Can you de-compile them? Are they obfuscated?

Comment: I don't have access to the classes.

Answer (score -1):

You want to automate user actions. There are a lot many software to do that, [WinAutomation](http://www.winautomation.com/)
,[AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml),
[AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)
and more...Searching Google would help